# I have linux installed on my macbook and i need to create a windows usb

Tags: boot, usb, macbook, macbook-pro

I have linux installed as my only OS on my macbook pro retina version and i need to create a installation usb that will boot on the usb...this has been frustrating for me and i need some help with this :/(internet recovery to get bootcamp IS NOT an option,the download is too long and my internet will cut off before it can install fully.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend using UNetBootin to make bootable usb drives (for both linux and windows distributions). A decent guide for making them can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Comment: To be clear you ARE using Ubuntu, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `dd` command:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/sdX && sudo sync
```

`/dev/sdX` = mounted usb-drive

Comment: This is the closest solution for me,but its not showing up in the menu when i hold ALT/option

Comment: No need for an interactive root shell...

Comment: For Windows 7, this will not work.

Comment: @davidbaumann: for Windows 7 You have to prepare the USB device and then properly copy the Windows 7 install files to it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use WinUsb (this commands works on Ubuntu 15.04 and lower)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Pendrive's Universal USB Installer (also known as UUI) and select the Windows option (there is Windows Vista to Windows 8 (or even Windows 10))

Comment: This answer is not detailed enough to be understood by people without advanced knowledge. I bet most users looking at this will even wonder what the heck "UUI" means...

Comment: Universal. USB. Installer.

Comment: And i've corrected it.